# Trying to read a vector from a textfile

Tags: c++, vector, text-files

```
    while (artist >> forname >> surname >> bandnum)
{
for (int i = 0; i <= bandnum; i++)
{
artist >> band[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i > bandnum; i++)
{
cout << band[i];
}
artist >> role;
```

The following code is how i am trying to read a vector from my text file, which is the form shown below

> john smith 3 a b c singer

The order must be read out in first name, second name, band number, bands they played for, and then their role. `Artist` is the ifstream and `bandnum` is the amount of bands they played for, with "a b c" being their bands. The `band` is a vector as the number of bands and what bands they played for will change for each artist. When i try run this the code breaks saying "vector subscript out of range". What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Neither of your loop conditions make much sense. I think in both cases you want `<`. You may also not be creating the elements in the `vector` before writing to them, but we can't know that without a full [mcve].

Comment: Is `band.size() >= bandnum` true? Your post doesn't include anything that sets its size.

Comment: @Shawn yes, it is equal

Comment: Good. Next fix the for loop issues already mentioned.

Comment: Done that but it isn't even getting to the second loop, it breaks at 'artist >> band[i];';

Comment: When you say 'it breaks', are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: @Worthwelle it comes up with a pop up asking to select break,continue or cancel. The error says "vector subscript out of range".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a wild guess, you aren't resizing band corrrectly (e.g. it's zero size). Probably you need to use `push_back` to add items to your vector.

```
while (artist >> forname >> surname >> bandnum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bandnum; i++)
    {
        string tmp;
        artist >> tmp;
        band.push_back(tmp);
    }
    artist >> role;
}
```